# Get container VC instead of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, containers

I'm a little confused how containers works. I have containers:
[image]

And i try to manage this in my `MainViewController`. But when i control-drag it into my .h file i'm getting

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *liveContainer;
```

Why this is an UIView class? This mean that is self.view my `BaseButtonContainerView`? But I have `BaseButtonContainerViewController`, and in debug i see that `viewDidLoad` is called. Can i get access to `BaseButtonContainerViewController` methods from `MainViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards like to do everything in the `prepareForSegue` so just assign your segue an identifier. In this case we'll assume you set it to `baseButtonContainerSegue` in IB. Then in `prepareForSegue` use :

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"baseButtonContainerSegue"]) {
        self.liveContainer = segue.destinationViewController;
    } 
}
```

Just make sure that you have a `UIViewController` property `liveContainer`, (specifically in your case you would want to have a `BaseButtonContainerViewController` property). I am not exactly sure why you have to do it this way but I am guessing it has something to do with memory management. Say you leave that screen and your containers are deallocated. Then when you go back you may lose your connection to them. This way the segues would be called again and you could grab them as properties. Again, I am not sure, so if someone else does please enlighten me!

Answer (score 0):

The controllers that are embedded in the container views are child view controllers of MainViewController, so you can access them with self.childViewControllers. That will give you an array of all your children, so you have to use objectAtIndex: to get to any one particular controller. The container views are just normal UIViews. The storyboard is just doing the work of setting up the child view controllers for you. What you get is the same as if you had used the custom container controller api to add the children yourself in code (with addChildViewController: and didMoveToParentViewController:, followed by adding the child's view to self.view or to a subview of self.view).