# iPAD application design with multiple visible views on the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am exploring the design options for an iPAD application with multiple views on the different part of the main screen. I am going to have different ViewController for each of the view. UI is quite different from what any of the available view controllers (UISplitViewController, UINavigationController etc.) provide.  I have been reading about the container extension api of UIViewController (especially addChildViewController):
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
(Look for "Implementing a Container View Controller")

However, it seems to me that this functionality is mainly designed for applications with UI that transition from one view to another (transitionFromViewController...). In my case, all of the views are visible at the same time. However, they do interact with each other. So my questions:

- Am I missing something w.r.t. container extension of View Controller? I will still probably end up using this just to keep the list of child view controllers but don't see much value.
- Can you recommend any other api/pattern that I should be using?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy access to childViewController.
`self.childViewControllers` will return an array with all childs.

I asked similar question couple days ago: Maybe this will help you:
[Get container VC instead of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940105/get-container-vc-instead-of-view)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html.

Add your various view controllers to `self.childViewControllers` and add the views of the child controllers as subviews of `self.view`.

Comment: I understand that I need to add every view as subview of the main view. However, I am not sure what I achieve by adding my view controllers (using addChildViewController), other than that I can access them later using self.childViewControllers.

Comment: How else would you store a reference to them? The child controllers need to have someone pointing strongly to them..

Comment: I plan to define strong @property to keep reference to each of the view controller. It is easier for me to interact with them this way instead of trying to find the right controller form the NSArray returned by childViewControllers.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. Lots of info on this topic.